# How To Determine Aggregate Root - Domain Driven Design

Tags: c#, oop, repository, domain-driven-design, domain-model

I have an aggregate: User.
How will I determine its aggregate root?

cause i have:

```
   +User(folder)
     - User(Abstract Class)
     * Administrator(Concrete inherits from User)
     * Manager(Concrete inherits from User)
     * Maintenance(Concrete inherits from User)
```

Also do I have to make a repository for each user class(admin, manager, maintenance)?
or just make 1 repository which uses the abstract class(User)?

Comment: You should probably read the paper by Vaughn Vernon on effective aggregate root design: http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/

Comment: I don't know what domain `User` is in but it might be better to call it `UserRole`. In many domains, a user can have multiple roles at the same time and role assignments that change over time.

Answer (score 4):

Your question has two, though related parts:
First, I think you notions of aggregate and aggregate root are not accurate. Hence, it is important to get them right before moving forward.

When you have an inheritance relationship, this is not an aggregate problem. Aggregate applies to composition. Here is why:

Let's take your own example. You have an abstract class User, and then you have these specializations of User: Administrator, Manager, Maintenance. Now, these four are not in an aggregate-aggregate-root relationship. But, they are all aggregate roots. Or in other words, each is aggregate root.

Starting from the user, let's say this is the aggregate root of an aggregate. Now, because an Administrator is-a User, you can replace a User with an Administrator, and it becomes the root. Same goes with other specilizations.

The key is to understand that Administrator, Manager, Maintenance are **replacements** for User in the same aggregate. They are not **object values** of User.

The second part of your question is about implementation. Whether to implement separate repository classes for each sub-type or a single one for all. The answer to this question depends on the particulars of your application, the kind of tools you use etc. There is no hard rule which of the two ways to chose. For example, if your subtypes differ in only few attributes, it may be better to have them all in single table and single repository, otherwise in have separate repositories. For example, the Hibernate Framework, allows either of the two ways and its up to the developer/designer to chose from.

But, again, the key is to think about this problem, as a inheritance (which it is) not an aggregate/aggregate-root problem.

Comment: Hi Nazar... thanks for helping me.. so in this case I'll just make each specialization an aggregate root then just use 1 repository for each of them cause there are only a few (like 2 or 3) difference in attribute for each specialization. but since my User is an abstract class so every time I query a record from the repository I need to identify specifically what specialization it is. am I right? but do I need to make a factory class for my User aggregate?

Comment: oh and im using entity framework btw.. but my domain model is persistence ignorance.. only know the IUserRepository, IWhateverRepository... thanks :)

Comment: I have used Hibernate Framework and a pattern called Generic Dao  Pattern (GDP) to deal with persistence like this. The idea of using GPD is to use Java's Generics. I am not sure how that translates to C#. Maybe C# folks can comment on that.

Comment: yup.. checked it out... C# has generic interface

Answer (score 1):

First it depends on your domain if User is an entity. For example in a Video rental store User is an entity an probably a good candidate for aggregate root. But if you gonna design a system for lets say recruiting. Then maybe User is just for login to the system. All users are allowed to do everything and all have same roles - recruiter. Then maybe user is more of a infrastructure thing and user may only be represented by a userid...somewhere among candidates. It all depends on User and the context.

About inheritance and repositories: Inheritance is a big deal to introduce. It can cause problems but can also reduce complexity. It depends if you have a lot of common behavior in common that can be placed in base class User. Then you can get a lot out of polymorphism and let there only be a UserService. UserService can then use AdministratorRepository or ManagerRepository when it's needed. But check if you can solve this by Composition instead of Inheritance. It don't creates to much coupling. It adds little more complexity when you want to extend with a new subclass.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Magnus... Ok so my domain will stay the same that way.. and having a UserService class that uses: IAdministratorRepository, IManagerRepository, ICashierRepository.. is fine.. but a lot of extra work in Infrastructure Repository code because you have to implement a difference repository for each.. but  it will work.. In my Database schema there is only one table: User that stores: admin, manager, cashier..etc and its field is overloaded only allow null if field is specific to a certain user but is not used..

Comment: although I might have to add a factory class for the user that is where my casting/polymorphism will work.. each user (admin, manager..etc) has its own different fields and the common ones are placed in the User(abstract class).. it seems that I wont have a specific aggregate root for the user aggregate cause a user can be: admin, manager, cashier..etc what will I do?

Comment: Not sure I follow your question. You still struggle with your AR's... I think you should stay away from inheritance if you can. But If you must I vote for having one AR User. Then you face two choices, letting the client do the casting from User to Admin or you can have a  function: Administrator UserRepository.GetAdministrator(int userId) that do the casting. Problem is that you need to make sure the userId is an administrator id, otherwise it will go BOOM. If you use Nhibernate with discriminator column you can face scenario when you select an instance that is not administrator

Comment: This can be solved by using special id sequence so you can determine that some id's are administrator id's or other id's are manager id's...

Comment: But as I mention before.... really try to avoid inheritance in Domain model if you can. It saves you a lot of headache

Comment: ahh ok.. i forgot to mention im not using special ids by the way i have an enum called: UserType.. will try composition.. thanks magnus...